# Using cv::VideoWriter in Mac OSX yields "WARNING: Could not create empty movie file container."

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv

I'm attempting to convert a list of images into a video file using OpenCV 4.3.2 in C++ on Mac OSX. The project is being compiled in XCode. Every time I run my code, the following output comes out:

> WARNING: Could not create empty movie file container.
>
> Didn't successfully update movie file.

The first warning is a result of:

```
    writer.open(argv[2],codec,fps,size);
```

And the second part about updating the movie file comes from:

```
    writer << im;
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    /*
        Skipping unrelated code
    */

    // Set FPS of movie
    double fps = 30;
    // Set frame size of movie
    cv::Size size = cv::Size(1920,1080);
    // VideoWriter stream to write images to
    cv::VideoWriter writer;
    int codec = CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X');

    std::cout << "Using codec " << codec << std::endl;

    // Open VideoWriter stream
    writer.open(argv[2],codec,fps,size);


    // Verify that the VideoWriter is open
    if(!writer.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "VideoWriter unable to open" << std::endl;
        return -3;
    }

    // Structure to hold image
    cv::Mat im;

    for(int i = 0; i < photos.size(); i++)
    {
        // Read image from file
        im = cv::imread(photos[i].c_str(), 1 );
    
        if(im.data != NULL )
        {
            std::cout << "Writing " << photos[i] << " to file." << std::endl;
            // Resize it to match video output
            cv::resize(im,im,size);
            // Write image to VideoWriter stream
            writer << im;
        }
        else
        {
            std:: cout << "Unable to read file " << photos[i] << std::endl;
        
            return -4;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've seen other people have similar errors, but none of the solutions fixed it (such as changing codecs, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  I tried changing codex and format.  The problem seemed to be when I created the directories in a string as stupid as that sounds. (Mac OSX, C++, Eclipse, opencv)

```
string directory = "directory/videos/";
VideoWriter out_capture(directory, 
    CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X'), frame_rate, Size(512,512));
```

When I added the directory in directly it worked:

```
VideoWriter out_capture("directory/videos/", 
    CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X'), frame_rate, Size(512,512));
```

If anyone comes up with a better solution I would love to hear it.